# django text input widget add google vocal input

Tags: django, widget, customization

I've noticed that Chrome offer the possibility of input text by speaking it.

Is there anything ready for django to enable this feature on the text input in forms?

Should I create a new widget? o alter one?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TextInput

the code to enable it is this:

```
 <input type="text" x-webkit-speech />
```

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1407892?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Just add the attribute to the widget:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
                                 attrs={'x-webkit-speech': 'x-webkit-speech'}))
```